# set value is not refreshing data in the form React hook form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I am using react hook form for building my app. i have 2 compnents: Parent is called mitigation and child is called PartnerForm:

in the parent i decalred:

```
// React-hook-form

      const methods = useForm({ mode: "all", defaultValues: mitigationDetails });
      const { control, setValue, getValues } = methods;
      const { fields } = useFieldArray({
        control,
        name: "partners"
      });
```

the child is called like that

```
 <div>
                {fields.map((field, index) => {
                  return <PartnerForm {...{ index, field }}></PartnerForm>;
                })}
              </div>
```

and in PartnerForm i declared:

// React-hook-form

```
  const {
    control,
    formState: { isSubmitted },
    setValue, getValues
  } = useFormContext();
```

example of fields in partner form

```
      <Controller
        name={`partners.${index}.name`}
        control={control}
        rules={{ required: mandatories.isPartnerNameMandatory }}
        render={({
          field: { onChange, onBlur, value },
          fieldState: { error, isTouched },
        }) => (
          <AutoComplete
            id="partnerNameInput"
            className={
              error && (isTouched || isSubmitted) ? "invalid" : "valid"
            }
            onChange={(e) => {
              onChange(e);
              reinitCpyDataExpectName(e.value);
            }}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            value={value}
            disabled={disableds.isPartnerNameDisabled}
            field="searchLabel"
            onSelect={(e) => {
              dispatch(
                updatePartner({
                  ...(foundedPartner as Partner),
                  idRicos: e.value.ricosId,
                  name: e.value.normalizedLegalName,
                })
              );
              //onEditingName(e.value.normalizedLegalName, true);
              processUnicornData(e.value.ricosId, true);
              setValue(
                `partners.${index}.name`,
                e.value.normalizedLegalName,
                {
                  shouldValidate: true,
                }
              );
            }}
            suggestions={cpySearchResult}
            completeMethod={searchCpyByName}
          />
        )}
      />
```

the problem here is when i do set values in mitigation form the data is not updated in partner form and when i call getValues i always have old values, any idea how to refresh values in the child component ?

```
  setValue("partners", mitigationDetails.partners, { shouldValidate: true });
```

Remark: when i do setValue(`partners.${0}.name`, 'test', { shouldValidate: true }); it works